# My beautiful soup code does not work as expected

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

It's my project and it does not work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import html

html_txt = requests.get("http://transfer.ttc.com.ge/?page=live&setLng=ka")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
job = soup.find("tr", class_= "text-left right txt-td")
print(job)
```

Comment: Your variable is named `html_txt` but later you use `html_text`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask].  Please write better titles and descriptions

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't make a soup with a Requests object, you should add .text:

```
html_text = requests.get("http://transfer.ttc.com.ge/?page=live&setLng=ka").text
```

You first call the variable `html_txt` and then `html_text`, there is something wrong...

You should try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
import html

html_text = requests.get("http://transfer.ttc.com.ge/?page=live&setLng=ka").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
job = soup.find("tr", class_= "text-left right txt-td")
print(job)
```